# NVT simulation of the phase transition

Tags: phase-transition, molecular-dynamics

Why it is assumed to be incorrect to simulate,say, liquid-solid transition at constant volume (NVT simulation)?

Comment: The transition usually comes with a change in volume (density), and fixing the volume of the container would stop this from happening. Instead of a transition, then, what you would likely end up with is a phase separation so that part of the container is one phase and the other part the other phase. That said, in simulations it is very easy to end up with artefacts due to finite size effects.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessarily incorrect, it depends on the system you're modelling.

A change in state is usually associated with a change in pressure. But in experimental situations the pressure is usually constant, which means that the volume of your simulation cell must change (hence you'd require NPT rather than NVT).

However, there are scenarios in which phase transitions occur at constant volume. Such as during crystallisation in confinement.

Comment: I would be interested in getting more examples of constant-volume phase transitions in one-component systems simulated by MD.